# Date time picker not working after setting autoUpdateInput to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have a requirement that when user has a date time exist in database only that time it shows date. But if database doesn't have date time then in text box it must be blank.

But when page load datetimepicker set default value in it. 
So for that I have set `autoUpdateInput` to false it's working it set textbox to blank. But after that the datetimepicker doesn't set value in textbox.

```
$('.datetimepicker').daterangepicker({ 
    autoUpdateInput: false,       
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    timePicker: true,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss'
    },
});
```

Js Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly0jh5pz/2/

**Note**: I have to use daterangepicker so bootstrap datetimepicker is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#reportdatetime").daterangepicker({
                autoUpdateInput: false,
        timePicker: true,
        timePicker24Hour: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 30,
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY H:mm'
        }
    });

  $('#reportdatetime').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY H:mm') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY H:mm'));
  });

  $('#reportdatetime').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });
```

Comment: Thank you brother . It's working as per the requirements.

Comment: i have same problem and now working perfectly but here is another problem onchange function not working now on this how can we set please help?

Comment: @NadeemIjaz, you can post it as a different question since it is a different problem than what OP posted.

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger `change()` to ensure it works perfectly in all cases; Sometimes you have some event listeners and need to trigger the change of date-range-picker.

```
$('#date-picker-input').daterangepicker({ 
  autoUpdateInput: false,       
  singleDatePicker: true,
  showDropdowns: true,
  timePicker: true,
  locale: {
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss'
  },
});

$("#date-picker-input").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A')).change();
});

$("#date-picker-input").on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val('').change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this format if you want to get datetime picker with timerange in single formate.
Below duetime is the id of your HTML input tag.

```
$("#duetime").daterangepicker({
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    startDate: false,
    minYear: 1901,
    showDropdowns: true,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    timePicker: true,
    timePicker24Hour: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 05,
    drops:"up",
    locale: {
        // format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'
    },
});

$("#duetime").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'));
});

$("#duetime").on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val('');
});
```